# TYPO3 automatic page creation based on TCA record

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I've special requirement on my project and I need help. I am using TYPO3 8.7.8. I've a custom extension to render tag labels in frontend. We can add the tags as TCA record in backend storage folder. In the TCA record, you can tag name. My requirement is, when I save the TCA record I want to create a TYPO3 page automatically with the same name as tag in a specific position. Everytime when I add a TCA record, I need to create corresponding page automatically. Is this possible? I can use hook while saving TCA. But is there any function to create pages automatically?

After automatic page creation, I want to insert a plugin content element in that page with a specific flexform value automatically. I know this is a strange requirement, but I would like to know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, you'd trigger a hook on saving and then as next step you can use the data handler to generate the new page (and possible content).

To create the page and content, use something like the following data structure

```
$data = [
   'pages' => [
       'NEW_1' => [
           'pid' => 456,
           'title' => 'Title for page 1',
       ],
    ],
    'tt_content' => [
        'NEW_123' => [
           'pid' => 'NEW_1',
           'header' => 'My content element',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then call the datahandler with that structure:

```
$tce = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\DataHandling\\DataHandler');
$tce->stripslashes_values = 0;
$tce->start($data, []);
$tce->process_datamap();
```

Find out more in the docs at
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html#data-array
and 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Let me try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need additional pages?

In general your problem sounds like you need one page where the plugin is inserted and where the plugin in dependency of an url-parameter (which can be converted with realurl into a path segment) shows only information depending of the selected record (tag).

If no tag is selected you can output a list with all available tags as a menu to navigate to all possible tags.

With a little effort (less than writing a hook like intended) you can add all tags to your menu.

Comment: The above datahandler helped me to create pages and content elements automatically. But I am facing a problem with updating flexform values automatically.